# How can I redirect a user to a user-specific homepage after login ? The user-specific url should contain the _id of the user

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect, redux, routes

```js
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <AppNavbar />
        <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/not-found" component={NotFound} />
            <AuthRoute path="/profile/settings" type="private">
              <Profile />
            </AuthRoute>
            <AuthRoute path="/setup/school" type="private">
              <SchoolDetails />
            </AuthRoute>
            <AuthRoute path="/setup/team" type="private">
              <TeamManagement />
            </AuthRoute>
            <AuthRoute path="/create/teams" type="private">
              <TeamSetup />
            </AuthRoute>
            <AuthRoute path="/register/setup" type="guest">
              <ProfileSetup />
            </AuthRoute>
            <AuthRoute path="/events" type="private">
              <SimpleSlider />
            </AuthRoute>
            <AuthRoute path="/register" type="guest">
              <RegisterModal />
            </AuthRoute>
            <AuthRoute path="/login" type="guest">
              <LoginModal />
            </AuthRoute>

            <AuthRoute exact path="/" type="private">
              <SimpleSlider />
            </AuthRoute>

            <Redirect to="/not-found" />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
  user: state.auth.user,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

```js
const AuthRoute = (props) => {
  const { isAuthenticated, user, type } = props;

  if (type == "guest" && isAuthenticated) {
    //history.replace(`${lo}/${user._id}`);
    return <Redirect to={`/events/${user._id}`} />;
  } else if (type == "private" && !isAuthenticated)
    return <Redirect to={`/login`} />;
  return <Route {...props} />;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
  userloaded: state.auth.userloaded,
  user: state.auth.user,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthRoute);
```

```js
const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
  isAuthenticated: null,
  userloaded: false,
  isLoading: false,
  user: null,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case USER_LOADED:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
        userloaded: true,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
    case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
      localStorage.setItem("token", action.payload.token);
      return {
        ...state,
        userloaded: true,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isLoading: false,
        ...action.payload,
      };
    case AUTH_ERROR:
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
    case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
    case REGISTER_FAIL:
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        user: null,
        userloaded: false,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

```js
export const loadUser = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // User loading
  dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING });

  axios
    .get("/api/auth/user", tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: USER_LOADED,
        payload: res.data,
      })
    )
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR });
    });
};

// Register User
export const register =
  ({ name, email, password }) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    // Headers
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    //Request body
    const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });

    axios
      .post("/api/users", body, config)
      .then((res) =>
        dispatch({
          type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
          payload: res.data,
        })
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(
          returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, "REGISTER_FAIL")
        );
        dispatch({
          type: REGISTER_FAIL,
        });
      });
  };

// Login User
export const login =
  ({ email, password }) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    // Headers
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    //Request body
    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

    axios
      .post("/api/auth", body, config)
      .then((res) =>
        dispatch({
          type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
          payload: res.data,
        })
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(
          returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, "LOGIN_FAIL")
        );
        dispatch({
          type: LOGIN_FAIL,
        });
      });
  };

// Logout User
export const logout = () => {
  return {
    type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
  };
};

// Setup config/headers and token
export const tokenConfig = (getState) => {
  // Get token from localstorage
  const token = getState().auth.token;

  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  // If token, add to headers
  if (token) {
    config.headers["x-auth-token"] = token;
  }

  return config;
};
```

My problem is that whenever a user logs in to my application he gets redirected to the homepage, but my "_id" from the redux store is undefined. First, after refreshing the page he get redirected to the URL including the correct user id.
For example,
after login => user gets redirected to "/events/undefined"
after another manual refresh => the URL changes to "/events/62a6503c9e8a60254ed94ff1"

sidenote: whenever the application gets refreshed the login site shows up for a split second. This is another unintentional behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for the sake of testing , may be you should try and check for the user object when you redirect ? like so:

```js
const AuthRoute = (props) => {
  const { isAuthenticated, user, type } = props;

  if (type == "guest" && isAuthenticated && user._id) {
    //history.replace(`${lo}/${user._id}`);
    return <Redirect to={`/events/${user._id}`} />;
  } else if (type == "private" && !isAuthenticated)
    return <Redirect to={`/login`} />;
  return <Route {...props} />;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
  userloaded: state.auth.userloaded,
  user: state.auth.user,
});
```

Comment: If I check for the user._id then the user gets logged in, but the user does not get redirected to the home screen. The application remains on the /login page, however, the navbar changes and gives me the option to log out.

Comment: It seems to be that the "isAuthenticated" variable of the initial state in my auth reducer gets updated before the user is loaded into the redux store. So isAuthenticated is true, but the user gets loaded a split second after, which makes the if-statement (if type == "guest" && isAuthenticated && user._id) false.

Comment: that makes sense...so you probaly shoud condition your authroute to the fact that user.id is defined or not, and before entering the other conditions that will redirect or not the user.. have you tried that ?

Comment: When I check if user._id is defined or not I am running into an error -> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id')

Comment: yes because user is still undefined at that time, so you could maybe test user instead of user._id

Comment: thank you so much, this fixed my error. I checked for a user before I did the other if statements and it works fine!

Comment: also I changed user._id to user.id